# Applying a formula to each row of a data frame of data frames using if else

Tags: r

I have a data frame of data frames where the 8th column of each data frame is a number. For every entry of that column, for every data frame, I want to use an if else statement to find out if the number is greater than 0.5. If it is greater than 0.5, I want to create a new column that contains the 1-(the number). If its less than .5, I want the new column to contain a replicate of the original number.

For example

```
[[1]]

DTM 2287  2 16  G 0.187500  C 0.812500

DTM 2290  2 16  A 0.187500  C 0.812500

DTM 2291  2 16  C 0.812500  G 0.187500

DTM 2293  2 16  T 0.000000  C 1.000000

DTM 2305  2 16  G 0.000000  C 1.000000
```

I would want to output to look like this:

[[1]]

```
DTM 2287  2 16  G 0.187500  C 0.812500 0.187500

DTM 2290  2 16  A 0.187500  C 0.812500 0.187500

DTM 2291  2 16  C 0.812500  G 0.187500 0.187500

DTM 2293  2 16  T 0.000000  C 1.000000 0

DTM 2305  2 16  G 0.000000  C 1.000000 0
```

I tried this:

```
files.x<-lapply(file.list, function(y){
if (test[,8] > 0.5) {
  test$fold=(1-x[,8])
} else {test$fold=x[,8]}})
```

But get an error about the column number being incorrect.

I've tried testing it on a single data frame, which sort of works, but it applies the function to every row instead of just those where the value is over .5

```
test2<-if (test[,8] > 0.5){test$fold=1-test[,8]} else {test$fold=test[,8]}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: For list `file.list` you can try: `lapply(file.list, function(x) transform(x, fold = if_else(x[,8] > .5, 1-x[,8], x[,8])))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `lapply` to loop over the list and use `ifelse` which is vectorized as compared to `if`/`else` which works on scalar values.

```
new_list <- lapply(file.list, function(y) 
                  {y$fold <- ifelse(y[,8] > 0.5,1-y[,8], y[,8]);y})
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `map` with `dplyr`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
new_list <- map(file.list,  ~ 
                     .x %>%
                        mutate(fold = case_when(.[[8]] > 0.5 ~
                                   1 - .[[8]], 
                          TRUE ~ .[[8]]))
```